# What is the probability of getting 4 cards number 2 in a 4-card hand?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting 4 cards number 2 in a 4-card hand? (There are 4 cards number 2 in heart, spade, club and diamond)

My guess is that there are 4 slots _ _ _ _. The probability of of the first card being number 2 is $\frac{4}{52}$, the second is $\frac{3}{51}$. the third is $\frac{2}{50}$ and the last one is $\frac{1}{49}$. The probability of getting all 4 number 2 cards is the product of these probabilities. Is this a correct solution?

Comment: Looks good.  As a variant, note that there is only one such hand and there are $\binom {52}4$ possible four card hands, so the answer is $1\big /\binom {52}4$.  But there is nothing at all wrong with your method.

Comment: Is it a sum or a product of these probabilities? I sometimes confuse the Rule of Addition and Rule of Mulitiplication.

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Product is correct.  You can check that my alternative method gives the product as well.

Comment: Product of probabilities: p12=p1 * p2 when they’re independent

Comment: @lulu: the result from your method and from mine is different from one another. Mine give $\frac{48}{6497400}=0.00000738757$. Yours is $\frac{1}{316251}=0.00000316204$

Comment: @JamesWarthington Your numerator should be $24$

Answer (score 1):

Another way this can be answered is by using counting principles.

$|A|$ is the size of the event that we get all four 2 cards.

$|S|$ is the size of the sample space.

Clearly we see that the sample space is just $52C4$, as from the 52 card deck, we can select a random of any 4 cards.

The size of A in this case is actually $4C4$, since we want to **specifically** selected all four 2's. There are four 2's in the deck, and we want to select all of them.

Hence the answer becomes:

$$\dfrac{\binom{4}{4}}{\binom{52}{4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about it is there are 52*51*50*49 possible 4-card hands. There is only 1 set {2h,2s,2c,2d} which constitutes a success. Since there are 4! permutations of the set, we get $\frac{4!}{52*51*50*49}$ as our probability, which agrees with your calculation.